# How can build android app using ionic framwork old version?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

One year before i install ionic framework and build one android app, that app is running sucessfully still now. But now i want some more enhancement for this app, so i am install ionic framework in another system and run the **ionic cordova build android** command in that project directory,  but it will throw below error.

> [WARN] ionic.project file found in C:\xampp\htdocs\officeapp--please rename it to ionic.config.json, or your project
>          directory will not be detected!
>
> [ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova build android
>           You may need to be in an Ionic project directory.
>
> Project Commands:
>    You are not in a project directory.

In that project directory there is no ionic.config.json. So i am install new project and compare the files in the new project i found ionic.config.json. And i compare bower.json files there is some version change, so i thing the version is the problem.

**Old project bower.json**

```
{
 "name": "HelloIonic",
 "private": "true",
 "devDependencies": {
  "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.1",
  "platform.js": "platform#^1.3.1"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "angular-messages": "1.3.6"
 }
}
```

**Newly created todo project**

```
{
 "name": "HelloIonic",
 "private": "true",
 "devDependencies": {
  "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.3"
 }
}
```

Please help anyone how can build app with old code, because all are working fine i want minmal change for this app.

Comment: you have to use command ionic build android not the ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 0):

As per your question explanation I see you are entering wrong command to build ionic project for the android platform.

> [ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova build android You may need to
>   be in an Ionic project directory.

Use following commands to build ionic project,

```
ionic build android
```

For more help please check [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/hybrid-mobile-apps-with-ionic-framework.html) for basic of Ionic.

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: thank u for reply.i try without codova it will throw [WARN] ionic.project file found in C:\xampp\htdocs\officeapp--please rename it to ionic.config.json, or your project
       directory will not be detected!
The build command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

  ionic cordova build --help

Comment: and this command **ionic cordova build android** working on newly created todo app

Comment: Okay So do one thing Can you please add the folders which are available in your project

Comment: And also let me know your ionic version

Comment: Can you trying running ionic build android and cordova build android? 
Also, can you run ionic info and paste the output here?